# Ratio between the corresponding force constants of Cl2 and F2

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecular-dynamics, molecular-mechanics

**MCQ Question:**

Vibrational frequency (f) of a diatomic molecule is given by

[image]

where  is the force constant and  is the reduced mass. For a diatomic molecule (AX), the reduce mass is given by

[image]

where  and  are mass of atom A and atom B respectively.

If vibrational frequencies (in wavenumber terms) of Cl2 and F2 in are 915 cm^-1 and 525 cm^-1
respectively, what is the ratio between the corresponding force constants of Cl2 and F2 (Cl2 : F2)?

(a) 5.7

(b) 6.0

(c) 6.3

(d) 6.7

(e) 7.1

The answer from MCQ is **A) 5.7**. I tried writing two equations for Cl2 and F2 and then dividing them but I got an answer of 1.74. How can I get 5.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diatomic molecules, $\mu = m/2$. This is $9.5$ for fluor and $17.75$ for chlorine.
Now $\pu{k}$ is given by :  $\pu{k = \mu* 4\pi^{2} f^2}$. If I use the index $1$ for chlorine and $2$ for fluorine, I can write : $$\pu{\frac{k_1}{k_2} = \frac{\mu_1 f_1^2}{\mu_2 f_2^2} = \frac{17.75}{9.5} * (\frac{915}{525})^2 = 5.67}$$

Comment: How did you get the reduced mass as m/2.

Comment: Use the given formula for $\mu$. Replace $\pu{m_x}$ by $\pu{m_a}$. You will obtain  :$\pu{\mu = \frac{m_a*m_a}{2m_a} = m_a/2}$